# Generate Nested List Django

Tags: python, django

I've got a spreadsheet like this. I have to generate a nested list. if parent id is 0, then it will have no parent i.e. root.

[image: Spreadsheet][image]

The resulted list will be look like below

[image: resulted list]

please show me a way to do this. Thanks

Comment: Have you tried anything by yourself? 

If no - try starting and then ask for help when you will have an issue.

Comment: give me some hints to get started

Comment: Start with pulling all elements from spreadsheet to some list or dictionary or whatever in python - then think what to do with that list once you have it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The general way to convert a list of tuples to a tree structure is by iterating over it and creating parent/children relationships:

```
data = [(newid, parentid, name), ...]  # getting the data into this format left as an excercise for the reader

# convert data into tree-structure
tree = {
    newid: {
        "parentid": parentid, 
        "name": name, 
        "parent": None, 
        "children": []
    } for newid, parentid, name in data }

for newid, item in data.items():
    node = tree[newid]
    if node['parentid'] is not None:
        parent = node['parent'] = tree[node['parentid']
        parent.children.append(node)
```

then you can find the root nodes by:

```
roots = [node for node in tree.values() if node.parent is None]
```

You can create a template tag to help display these, or you can do it in javascript, e.g. if you pass `roots` to your template as `json.dumps(roots)`:

```
<div id="mylst"></div>
<script>
(function drawroots(pos, roots) {

    let draw_leaf = function (n) {
        return '<li> + n.name + '</li>';
    };

    let draw_subtree = function (n) {
        let res = "<li>" + n.name + "<ol>";
        n.children.forEach(c => {res += draw_node(c); });
        res += "</li></ol>";
    };

    let draw_node = function (n) {
        return (node.children.length === 0) ? draw_leaf(n) : draw_subtree(n);
    };

    $(pos).append('<ol>');
    roots.forEach(r => {
        $(pos).append(draw_node(r));
    });
    $(pos).append('</ol>');
}('#mylst', {{roots}});
</script>
```

there are much better ways to do this in js, but this should get you started.